# Broken stick problem

Tags: complexity-theory, algorithms, dynamic-programming

We have a broken stick. For every part, we know it's length. Our task is to connect all parts (glue them), that we will use as small amount of glue as possible.

The amount of glue need to connect two parts equal the maximum from their sizes. We can only glue two parts at one time.Can we solve this problem in the time complexity smaller than $O(n^3)$? I know only the answer, using dynamic table in this complexity

Comment: It is a bit strange that the amount of glue changes depending on the length - why? O(n^3) is an at most notation - probably you want to know if we can solve it in o(n^3) time.

Comment: Do the parts have a fixed position (in the "reconstructed" stick)? Or can they be rearranged arbitrarily?

Comment: If I understand correctly, the problem looks like the construction of a Huffman tree.  If so, the problem would be solved in O(n log n) time.

Comment: Could you please explain why you are interested in this question and provide motivation?

Comment: @Kaveh Just my tutor ask us to find a solution on the web if someone is interested. That's not a homework.

Comment: @MarzioDeBiasi - No, the parts have fixed order in the glued stick.

Comment: I think I misunderstood the problem.  So, my previous comment doesn't apply to this problem.

Comment: I have given _very_ similar questions in homework and exams in my undergraduate algorithms course.  This should be migrated to CS.SE.

Comment: @JɛﬀE Could You do this? Or I can do this somehow?

Comment: This is similar to the "multiply matrices in optimal fashion" problem that is usually given as a dynamic programming example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't define what 'connecting all parts' is. Do you need to arrange them in an array? Or just connect them?

The way I understood the problem, you can use Prim's algorithm to find the minimum spanning tree, and that's the result. O(n^2)

In case you want them arranged in an array, I think the sorted array is always optimal.

We will call a part "counted" if it is the bigger part in some connection. A part can be counted 0, 1, or 2 times. Let there be 3 elements in the array that are not sorted (A > B > C). Let L be the part placed left from this sequence, and R the part placer right. The ordering is L(permutation(A,B,C))R. You can observe all cases, and see that the permutation ABC is the best because it takes the parts max(L,A), A, B, max(C,R). This proves that all 3 element subsequences should be sorted, which means the sorted array is optimal.

Answer (score 4):

Homework?

See the problem "Cutting Wood", which involves cutting rather than glueing, but is otherwise equivalent. Provided the orders matters (as noted by Marzio).

> Your favorite sawmill charges by length to cut each board of lumber. 
>   For example, to make one cut anywhere on an 8 ft. board of lumber costs \$8. 
>   The cost of cutting a single board of wood into
>   smaller boards will depend on the order of the cuts.
>   As input, you are given a board of length $n$ marked with $k$ locations to cut

[solution to exercise](http://courses.csail.mit.edu/6.046/spring04/handouts/ps6sol.pdf) (pdf) Found in several places on the web, don't know the original.